# Java 9 Nested (Hierarchical or Parent/Child) Modules

Tags: java, java-9

Is it possible to create inheritance-based (or nested) modules in Java 9?

Something like this:

```
module a
   |
   ├── module a1
   |   
   └── module a2
```

In this example, both the `a1` and `a2` modules are children of `a`.

If I import either of the child modules, I would get the functionality of the parent (`a`) along with any functionality defined in that child.  That is, I could import `a1`, and explicitly gain access to the functionality of both `a` and `a1` (but not `a2`).

Both `a1` and `a2` are an `a`, and can access all of the packages of `a`, without having to expose the packages of `a` to them.

Comment: I don't really understand what are these relations between modules. Does `a` require the `a1`? The opposite? What does it mean "dependencies of module a is based on a1"? What does it mean with behavior? It's a lot less general question which you seem to believe.

Comment: It would be useful to expand the question to explain what you are trying to do. Maybe you want module a to be an aggregator module (`module a { requires transitive a1; requires transitive a2; }` so that anyone that requires a will be able to access the APIs exported by a1 and a2?

Comment: @AlanBateman I took it to mean the opposite; there are two externally-facing modules (`a1` and `a2`) which are both `a` modules (in that they can access all of the packages of `a`, without having to expose the packages of `a` so that they, themselves, can access it).  Which is to say, I agree the question should be clarified.

Comment: If what I stated is the desired behavior, I'm not sure you actually want this, in general; what is stopping me from saying that I'm a submodule of `a` to access otherwise-inaccessible elements of `a`?  It's compromising security.  If `a` was to allow submodules of itself, then I think, for security, you would want those submodules to be explicitly spelled out in `a` (not allowing just anyone to claim they are a submodule).  You might be able to handle what you want with `exports X to Y`?

Comment: In some other programming languages environments, like ```php```, there is a concept called nested modules. In this concept a module (parent) is created using multiple modules (child). The overall functionality of the parent module is the functionality of the parent module itself, plus the functionalities which those child modules provide. For example if you want to execute the child module, the parent module will be executed either. I know it seems a bit weird and having this hierarchical structure is not necessary, but I wanted to know of there is such thing in Java 9.

Comment: @HamidMohayeji, we aren't using PHP here, and java modules are different from PHP ones. There is no notion of module being "executed" in Java.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I just gave you an example. But anyway thanks for reminding me we are not using ```php``` here.

Comment: @HamidMohayeji I have edited your question with my understanding of what you desire.  If you feel this is not correct, please clarify the question.  If you feel like the question as worded is what you are looking for, then check my answer below.

Comment: @HamidMohayeji With respect to your edited question, the answer is (at the time of writing) that it cannot be done.  With respect to the statement "[...] can access all of the packages of `a`, without having to expose the packages of `a` to them.", it would generally be unsafe if modules could be utilized in such a way.  The purpose of Java modules are to restrict visibility (in a more versatile manner than the previous packaging mechanics allowed), and this would tear apart those restrictions.  `a` needs to be in control of how it exports.

Comment: @Ironcache thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can *emulate* what you asked for with a combination of `requires transitive` and `exports to` syntax:

- `requires transitive`: Specifies that importing this module will inherently import another module.  You can use this to ensure that `a1` and `a2` cause `a` to be imported.
- `exports to`: This will let you export functionality to a specific module only; this will allow you to let `a` give access to `a1` and `a2` functionality that would be dangerous to have publicly exported.

So, for examples sake:

```
module a {
    exports com.internal to a1;
    exports com.internal to a2;
}

module a1 {
    requires transitive a;
}

module a2 {
    requires transitive a;
}
```

In this case, if a consumer depends on `a1`, they will inherently depend on `a` (thus gaining the utilities of both), and the `com.internal` package, while visible to `a1` for internal use, will not be externally visible to the consumer.

It is not quite what you asked for.  `a1` is **not** an `a`.  Further, `a1` **can not be made to be** an `a`; the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7) does not allow for wildcards in exports (IE: `exports * to a1`, which still wouldn't make `a1` an `a` but would bring it closer from a pragmatic perspective), and no other syntax exists in modules to allow for it.